# Rails + model.rb issues -- rails console error message -- "Object doesn't support #inspect"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, object, model, rails-models

EDIT3:
To wit, DO NOT put migration code in your model.rb files!!!

EDIT2: THE QUESTION (?) :
does ANY migration code belong in a model.rb file?

EDIT: Just mentioning extra (system/config/etc) information that I need to share in order to get a good answer to this question from someone (even if it's not you) would be greatly appreciated. (1-ups for good tips on stack overflow optimization strategies)

First of all, here is the command prompt activity:

```
C:\Users\davo\Desktop\RailsProjects\simple_cms>rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
irb(main):001:0> subject = Subject.find(1)
←[1m←[36mSubject Load (1.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT `subjects`.* FROM `subjects` WHERE       `subjects`.`id` = 1
LIMIT 1←[0m
=> #<Subject id: 1, name: "Initial Subject", position: 1, visible: true, created_at:"2012-05-18 01:00:26", updated_at: "2012-05-18 01:11:21">
irb(main):002:0> subject.pages
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
```

The basic schema is that we have two models here, page.rb and subject.rb. Subject is the parent of Page, as you will see. Here are the two models.

**Guide to viewing this code: I think all that is relevant to this problem in these two models are the has_many and belongs_to tags. And I admit, I feel like there should be some foreign keys here. Should there be foreign keys here? Or is that wrong too?**

subject.rb

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  has_many :pages

  scope :visible, where(:visible => true)
  scope :invisible, where(:visible => false)
  scope :search, lambda {|query| where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])}
end
```

page.rb

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :sections
  belongs_to :subject
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  create_table "Pages" do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "permalink"
  t.integer "position"
  t.boolean "visible?"

  end
end
```

I'm really new at this, so please forgive me if I didn't give you some piece of information that you need. Please let let know what extra information you need, I'm not sure where the error is coming from but I know this is a model (M....VC) issue. 95% on that one.

Comment: What you have here so far looks ok, other than the errant `end` in page.rb.

Comment: I noticed that too earlier. But assumed that the create_table method needed that "end". Trying the changes now.

Comment: EDIT: RubyMine shows an error for not adding an end for the create_table method. The do |t| needs an end.

Comment: But wait...you're not supposed to do migrations in a model.rb file are you? Hmmmm checking things.

Comment: oh, i see. i didn't realize because the inner block wasn't indented, yes the `create_table` needs the `end`. You don't do migrations in models, though. You generate a migration with `rails g migration migration_name`, then put the code in the generated file.

Comment: for the love of God, don't put migrations in a model.  I don't know what resources you are using to learn Rails, but maybe try this: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Comment: Agree with @AndrewKuklewicz on ruby.railstutorial.org, if you're willing to part with a few shekels http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails is a good book and https://peepcode.com/products/meet-rails-3-i is excellent screencast (plus you retain more than through book)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a migration in your model.

```
create_table "Pages" do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.string "permalink"
  t.integer "position"
  t.boolean "visible?"
end
```

Should be in ./db/migrate/{timestamp}_create_pages.rb. This file was generated for you if you did `rails g model page`

You also need a `subject_id` column to store the relation to subject

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pages do |t|
      t.integer :subject_id
      t.string :name
      t.string :permalink
      t.integer :position
      t.boolean :visible?

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```